# joomla 3 component for allow customers to buy and sell

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i want component for **Joomla 3**
to allow customers buy product like **shop** and customers can be **seller** and create product for sell.

Comment: need to check this page first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you read that page or before reading you gave your special comment? This is for programmers and not asking opinion for something. If you have difficulty in programming or you have tried something and failed then you need to ask it here. Dont expect spoon feeding.

Comment: @AmitRay call 911 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few Joomla extensions with options to create a multi vendor shop. For example:

- [Hikashop](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/hikashop) with [HikaMarket](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/extension-specific/hikashop-extensions/hikamarket)
- [jMarket](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jmarket)
- [Sellacious](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sellacious)

Answer (score 0):

You can try DJ-Catalog2 as well, but check the features in detail to be sure it has all you need. Tech support is good too.